# WSP contains a TermSet but it isn't imported

Tags: solution-package, import, term-store

We've exported a Site Collection which contains Term Set navigation as a WSP.

Opening the WSP as a Cab I can see that it contains the TermSet

However, whether I use Powershell to deploy the WSP at a Web Application level the GUI to deploy it at Farm level, the actual Term Set is not imported.

I see there are lots of tools around to manually export/import term sets, but I would have thought that if the WSP contains the Terms then SharePoint would bring them through - it's like Microsoft only got as far as writing the export bit and never wrote the import routines?

Any suggestions please of a way that doesn't require us to manually recreate and reattach all the terms (or rewrite the one of the powershells that are out there for 2010).  It'd be ideal to use a Microsoft way of doing it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the WSP contains the TermSet. How you included it in the WSP? You can use a `FeatureReceiver` to programmatically create those.

Comment: Well, we didn't explicity export the Term Set, but when I poked around in the WSP (by converting it to a CAB) I could see a TermSet{GUID}.dat file in the Modules/Files/_catalogs/masterpage/TaxonomyLocalData  folder, hence my wondering why it SharePoint doesn't import it (no matter whether you put the WSP in via Powershell, Farm Import or Site Solution Addition).  I think we will have to use a CSV export/import - powershell scripts not a problem, just disappointed there's no OOB way to do it :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have since discovered that SharePoint will silently fail to import Navigation Termsets if the TermSet Administrator is incorrectly set at the top level.  But it will pull through the other termsets.

Going to Central Admin Term Store Manager (_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx) make sure the Term Store Administrators are set up as the user you want to run the powershell as.

You can then use the code from 
https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/importing-taxonomy-to-sharepoint-using-powershell/

to pull in your termsets.